# The clutch keeps going out in my truck

Tags: ford, ranger, clutch-hydraulics

my 94 ford ranger was fine then all the sudden the clutch went out. It wont go into gear and when you try and put it in reverse it grinds really loud. i have replaced the master cylinder three times and the slave cylinder twice. The fluid was gone and i put fluid back in it and it started working fine but today the gears are out but the resavoir is still full of fluid. What can be causing this issue? why does the clutch keep going out?

Comment: Does it go into gear when the engine is off? Did you bench bleed the master or slave cylinders?

Answer (score 1):

You say the clutch is out. But have you replaced the clutch, pressure plate, throw out bearing and pilot bearing ? If you lost the fluid its gotta have a leak or  had one bad air bubble. Make sure it's bled correctly.